# Prevent Exposing Actual URL

Tags: php, redirect

I have a php file that needs to be called directly.  It renders PDF content and outputs it via application/pdf headers so the user doesn't leave the page they called from.

This php file is located in the depths of my php libraries folder structure.  I'm currently linking to the php file like so:

```
<a href="myserver.com/path/to/actual/phpFile/downloadPDF.pdf?arg1=blah&arg2">
```

I would rather my users not know details like directory names and php files.  Security by obfuscation, right?

What's the best way to create a redirect that does what I'm looking for?

Comment: Hiding your directory structure does not help security.  Benefits would be purely cosmetic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easier solution is to find or create `.htaccess` file which you should then place in the `htdocs` directory.

Add these lines of code in it:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)yournewaddress$  /path/to/actual/phpFile/downloadPDF.pdf?arg1=blah&arg2
```

Then you can call your pdf file with

```
<a href="myserver.com/yournewaddress">
```

Answer (score 1):

If using Apache, you could try this rewrite rule to produce a nice, human-readable URL

```
# in server-config
RewriteRule ^/download/pdf/(.+) /path/to/actual/phpFile/downloadPDF.php?args=$1 [L,QSA]
```

(if using `.htaccess`, omit the leading forward-slashes)

You could then use a URL like

```
<a href="/download/pdf/blah">
```

Anything after the `pdf/` will be placed into the `$_GET['args']` variable which you can use as you see fit. For multiple args, I'd recommend separating them with a slash, eg

```
/download/pdf/foo/bar
```

... and in `downloadPDF.php`

```
$args = isset($_GET['args']) ? explode('/', $_GET['args']) : array();
```

Answer (score 0):

put

```
<?php
include "path/to/actual/phpFile.php";
?>
```

into downloadPDF.pdf in your webroot and link to that.

Comment: If the .pdf file is a PDF file this is a bad idea. If the .pdf file is a PHP file, I'm confused why it's got a .pdf extension.

Comment: OQ: "I have a php file that needs to be called directly. It renders PDF content", so "path/to/actual/phpFile.php" is the PHP file and /downloadPDF.pdf is just decoration to make stupid browsers happy

Comment: If the PDF just happens to have `<?php` in it, you run the risk of PHP attempting to run it.

Comment: Then there's no point in all this.  The url structure is better handled with rewrites.  Screw having a PHP file whose only purpose is to include another.

Comment: The OQ was: "I would rather my users not know details like directory names", so this is exactly what my little hack does: It hides the directories (and does so without touching the server configuration)